# How to display List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> in WPF View XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a List< KeyValuePair< string, string>> StatusValue

which i populate with 9 KeyValue pairs

I need help with how am I supposed to print that onto view in this fashion:

Key Value

Key Value

Key Value..

For now I tried something like:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,30,0,0" x:Name="StatusValue"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusValue}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Key"
             SelectedValuePath="Value">
    </ListBox>
```

however that doesn't seem to be working at all.

Comment: `StatusValue` should be a public property of the object in the DataContext of your ListBox (or one of its parent elements). If you want to display both Key and Value, you should declare a DataTemplate with two TextBlocks in the ListBox's ItemTemplate, instead of setting DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: @Clemens O/T IIRC saw you recommend a WPF book in a comment the other day. Somebody just asked me for a recommendation and I didn't have one. Do you recall what the book was?

Comment: @Ed It was [WPF Unleashed](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/) by Adam Nathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Listbox is just a container. You need to define a template for it, in which you specify how to display the items. For instance you can do:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,30,0,0" x:Name="StatusValue"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusValue}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <WrapPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
              </WrapPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```